# Application Defined or oBject Defined Error - Cannot Solve

Tags: excel, vba

```
 Sub gains()

 Dim date_data As Long 
 Dim date_h As Long 
 Dim cell As Range 
 Dim analysis_rng As Range 
 Dim data_h As Range

 Set analysis_rng = Application.Worksheets("DataDPI").Range("A2:A107")
 Set data_h = Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:A525")

 For Each cell In analysis_rng

 cell.Offset(0, 2) = data_h.Find(cell, LookIn:=xlValues)


 Next cell


 End Sub
```

It was working and then stopped working. Data is the same and the worksheets are labeled correctly. Error 1004

Spent 15 minutes trying to debug already

I can fill the cell.offset(0,4) with text/number just fine but I can no longer do data_h.find (range.find). i was testing it earlier and was working okay```

**Purpose**

I have a main dataset, it's a bunch of dates open close prices: workhseet "Data"

Secondary set is a select few dates from the main data set and other . I am just trying to see what changes are but before that, I just want to make sure i'm referencing the right data

So in the code posted above, once it was copying over the right data from "data" to cell.offset, I was going to just use offset to collect data as I wanted from main set: data_h to the new "DataDPI"

Comment: You should specify the other parameters for `Find`, especially `LookAt`

Comment: Still gives an error. I look inside the local tab and see the "     : Errors : <Application-defined or object-defined error>. This is for both the ranges I defined, not sure why

Comment: That code wouldn't compile. Looks like you have some serious formatting issues. Let's start with the basisc: One Dim per line. Indent. Use `Option Explicit`. Use `.Value` or `.Text` when trying to pull data from cells.

Comment: 1. The formatting copied poorly, i do have them as seperate line items
2. cell is just an empty range variable to reference a range/cell (to loop through). What I am doing is I am just addingto the main post for clarity
3. Also tried .value but it wasn't working

Comment: Generally when using Find() you should assign the return value to a Range variable and then test that using (eg) `If Not myRange Is Nothing` before doing anything with it (such as trying to read its value)

Comment: @TimWilliams I just realized that I'm not able to declare the variables as Range.As in when I do " dim analysis_rng  as Range", the range is not blue. but i am able to access the cell in one of  the ranges as I can still set them. I tried variant and that doesn't work either

sure, that's error handling but I set up the data so there is no mistake. Confused why I can't intialize a range, and the

Comment: Did you name something else as "Range" ?  A code module/worksheet code name, etc?

Comment: Nope. This is so strange

Comment: Code is working for me and as @Tim Williams said you need to check the result of `Find`. Or in other words I also get an RTE 1004 in case the result of `Find` is `Nothing` what I expected and therefore _Code working_ .

Comment: Try creating a new workbook and see if you have the same problem there

Comment: already tried that since that's worked in the past. I'm gonna maybe rebuild everything from scratch or just move on to something else